# Почему i[array] подобен array[i]?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели

Не совсем понятно:

```
int i;

int array[anySize];
```

Почему запись `arr[i]` эквивалентна `i[arr]`?

Answer (score 4):

`arr` это просто указатель на первый элемент массива (`arr == &arr[0]`) То есть `arr[i] == *(&arr[0] + i)`. Это просто синтаксический сахар, который и так работает. Я думаю вы поторопились, в книге по которой вы изучаете язык просто обязано быть об этом.

Comment: `arr[i] == *(&arr[0] + i)`

Comment: Да, простите, это случайность. Спасибо.

Comment: `arr` - это "просто указатель на первый элемент массива" только в value contexts. В данном случае мы имеем дело именно с value context.

Answer (score 4):

Потому как все равно "за сценой" все это преобразуется в указатель с помощью арифметики `arr+i`, а как известно, `a+b == b+a` :)

Comment: Это не вполне корректное объяснение. `int` + `pointer` **определено как** `pointer` + `int`, и только поэтому выполняется равенство. Сложение не определено везде, например, нельзя складывать два указателя. Поэтому нельзя сказать, что это так из одного определения сложения. (Тем более, что общее значение равно не `(int)arr + i`, а `(int)arr + i * sizeof(*arr)`.)

Comment: @VladD У меня не объяснение, почему так (на самом деле могли сделать как угодно, вплоть до того, что побайтно указатель смещать при суммировании...), а скорее объяснение, *чем руководствовались*, когда так стандарт делали. Само собой, можно было сделать совершенно иначе, но не в последнюю очередь сыграло это арифметическое соображение.

Comment: Понял. Тогда, возможно, имеет смысл объяснить немного больше в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что [стандарт](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). Смотрите пункт 5.2.1:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “array
>   of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration
>   or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T” shall be a
>   completely-defined object type.64 The expression E1[E2] is identical
>   (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of
>   * and
>   + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ], except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is
>   an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

Гугл-переводчик:

> Постфиксное выражение, за которым следует выражение в квадратных
>   скобках, является постфиксным выражением. Одно из выражений должно
>   иметь тип «массив Т» или «указатель на Т», а другой должен иметь
>   неперечисленное перечисление или интегральный тип. Результат имеет тип
>   «T». Тип «T» должен быть полностью определенным типом объекта.
>   Выражение E1 [E2] идентично (по определению) к * ((E1) + (E2))
>   [Примечание: См. 5.3 и 5.7 для деталей * и + и 8.3.4 для получения
>   подробной информации о массивах. - end note], за исключением того, что
>   в случае операнда массива результат равен lvalue, если этот операнд
>   является lvalue и xvalue в противном случае.

Comment: Но в стандарте нет того, что `(E1) + (E2) == (E2) + (E1)`. (Это не самоочевидно, т. к. для указателя и числа результат численно равен `(E1) + (E2) * sizeof(элемент массива)`.)

Comment: @VladD я этого и не утверждал. Просто процитировал стандарт.

Comment: Но в таком случае это не объясняет того, почему `arr[i]` — то же, что и `i[arr]`. Ваша цитата говорит лишь, что `arr[i] == *(arr + i)` и `i[arr] == *(i + arr)`, но не почему эти выражения равны.

Comment: Из этого: `arr[i] == *(arr + i) и i[arr] == *(i + arr)` как раз и следует, что `arr[i] == i[arr]`. Тут конечно надо еще доказать, что `arr + i == i + arr`, но в замечании есть отсылка к оператору `+`. Думаю в описании оператора `+` этот случай описан.

Comment: Ну тогда дополняйте куском стандарта про +. Без этого ответ выглядит как-то так: «Почему первая штука равна второй? Потому что первая равна третей, а вторая равна четвёртой.»